# Initialize object in database in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, initialization, entity-framework-6

The application does not run when I use this to initialize the objects in my DB:

```
public class MiradorInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MiradorContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MiradorContext context)
    {
        Client tom = new Client("Tom", "De Backer");
        Booking bookingtom = new Booking("21-02-12", "05-03-12", 450);
        bookingtom.Client = tom;

        Client jeroen = new Client("Jeroen", "De Backer");
        Booking bookingjeroen = new Booking("01-06-13", "16-09-13", 5460);
        bookingjeroen.Client = jeroen;

        context.Bookings.Add(bookingtom);
        context.Bookings.Add(bookingjeroen);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But it does when I initialize these objects and .SaveChanges in my main method. Is there something wrong with my approach of an initializer?

```
public class Program
{
    private static IEnumerable<Booking> bookings;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MiradorContext context = new MiradorContext();
        Client tom = new Client("Tom", "De Backer");
        Booking bookingtom = new Booking("21-02-12", "05-03-12", 450);
        bookingtom.Client = tom;

        Client jeroen = new Client("Jeroen", "De Backer");
        Booking bookingjeroen = new Booking("01-06-13", "16-09-13", 5460);
        bookingjeroen.Client = jeroen;

        context.Bookings.Add(bookingtom);
        context.Bookings.Add(bookingjeroen);
        context.SaveChanges();
        Console.ReadKey();
        readBookings(context);
    }

    public static void readBookings(MiradorContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n---Opvragen alle bookings---");
        var bookings = from b in context.Bookings
                       orderby b.Client.Familienaam
                       select b;
        foreach (Booking booking in bookings) { 
            Console.WriteLine(booking.Id + ": " + booking.Client.Familienaam + " " + booking.Client.Voornaam+" - Van "+booking.DatumVan+" tot "+booking.DatumTot+" voor "+booking.Prijs+" euro."); 
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MiradorContext class constructor make sure you do set the initialiser like this

```
static MiradorContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MiradorContext>(new MiradorInitializer());
}
```

Comment: Thanks my school course had a complete explanation and example but this line somehow was excluded.